# WP_Query to Retrieve Posts from WooCommerce Products that are Only in Catalog

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a handful of products in my WooCommerce Store set to `Catalog & Search` and a bunch more just set to a visibility of just `Search`.

I put a lot of work into making sure my Catalog was nice and clean, but now I need to do some additional work on them and am trying to retrieve the IDs of products that are ONLY in my Catalog and not just search.

I've tried a few things, but something is amiss somewhere.

What am I missing?

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'menu-order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' =>
    array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'value' => 'exclude-from-catalog',
            'compare' => '!=')
        ));
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
$ids = $wc_query->posts;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ids);
echo '</pre>';
```

With this Query it's still returning all Product IDs.

I'm assuming there must be something wrong with my `meta_query` argument.  What I was going for was to look for the `product_visibility` `taxonomy` and exclude (`!=`) those that have the value `exclude-from-catalog`.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted too quick.  Found a solution shortly after

This works:

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'menu-order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' =>
    array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 7,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN')
        ));
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
$ids = $wc_query->posts;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ids);
echo '</pre>';
```

note the `term` id `7` is `exclude-from-catalog`

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you're using `meta_query` and passing the parameters of a `tax_query`. You have to change your code to this if you're searching for a `meta value`:

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'menu-order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' =>
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'product_visibility',
            'value' => 'exclude-from-catalog',
            'compare' => '!=')
        ));
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
$ids = $wc_query->posts;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ids);
echo '</pre>';
```

or this, if its a `term`

```
   $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'menu-order',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' =>
        array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field' => 'slug'
                'terms' => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                'compare' => 'NOT IN')
            ));
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    $ids = $wc_query->posts;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ids);
    echo '</pre>';
```

See more about [tax_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).